# Mount win share access after 18.04 update in mate

Tags: mount, samba, mate

I am a very new user and not at all familiar with any of the commands. I have searched and tried cutting and pasting many of the directions to link access to my win computer where many of my files reside, photos, spread sheets, etc. I love the operating system for running so well as my windows machines continue to endlessly update....

I started out about a month ago and loaded ubuntu 16.04 mate and loved it connected to my win machine and all was great, got notice to update and went ahead it went fro 16 to 17 then to 18. since i have not been able to setup access to my win shared folders.  Again am very new not at all familiar with terminology and commands. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the `help.ubuntu.com` pages may help
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html

See 'Windows Share' section

Comment: ml@ml-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo testparm
[sudo] password for ml: 
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Error loading services.
ml@ml-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo smbclient -L //server -U user
smbclient: Can't load /etc/samba/smb.conf - run testparm to debug it
ml@ml-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ smb://mike-pc/Share
bash: smb://mike-pc/Share: No such file or directory
ml@ml-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ 

Above is some of the stuff getting  Think using Caja as my file mgr not finding command to find other places....

Comment: Open a terminal and run: caja smb://mike-pc/Share

Comment: Message "could not display "smb://mike-pc/share/"      Error:Failed to mount share: invalid argument please select another viewer and try again."

Comment: And what is the error when you run: smbclient -L //mike-pc -U mike -mSMB1

Comment: "WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'SMB1' for parameter 'client max protocol'
smbclient: Can't load /etc/samba/smb.conf - run testparm to debug it"                             Thank you for taking time to help! OzMax

Comment: I also rebooted between the last exchange and this one

Comment: Sorry. Rookie mistake on my part. Try this: smbclient -L //mike-pc -U mike -mNT1

Comment: ml@ml-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ smbclient -L //mike-pc -U mike -mNT1
smbclient: Can't load /etc/samba/smb.conf - run testparm to debug it
ml@ml-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: Unless you want to move this to the Ubuntu forum I would suggest you go to your original question and add the entire contents of your smb.conf file - if there is one: cat /etc/samba/smb.conf